# Spark SQL output multiple small files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

We are having multiple joins involving a large table (about 500gb in size). The output of the joins is stored into multiple small files each of size 800kb-1.5mb. Because of this the job is split into multiple tasks and taking a long time to complete.

We have tried using spark tuning configurations like using broadcast join, changing partition size, changing max records per file etc., But there is no performance improvement with this methods and the issue is also not fixed. Using coalesce makes the job struck at that stage and there is no progress.

Please view this link for Spark UI metrics screenshot, https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfyYy.png

Comment: Coalesce was added right after join or right before writing output files? What number of partitions was passed to this function?

Answer (score 1):

The spark UI confirms your report of too many small files. You will get a file for every spark partition, and you have 33,479 in your final stage where you're writing the output. 33k partitions was probably the right number of partitions for your join but not the right number for your write.

You need to add another stage in your job that comes after your join. That 2nd needs to reduce the number of spark partitions to a reasonable number (that outputs 32MB - ~128MB files)
Something like a coalesce, or repartition. Maybe even a sort :(
You want to target ~350 partitions.

This diagram shows what you want to do manually or automatically (with spark on Databricks)
[image: Traditional Writes vs Optimized Writes]

If you're using Databricks then it's easy as with Delta Lake you can turn on [Auto Optimize](https://docs.databricks.com/optimizations/auto-optimize.html)